# Testing and workflow capabilities keep failing

Tags: virtual-machines, testing, team-foundation-server, automated-testing

My testing and workflows are failing.

The workflow fails for this reason.
[image]

But I have the TFS build service on the environment and the agent has the green light beside it.

The testing fails for this reason.
[image]

I have the test controller on the TFS machine and the test agent on the environment, I don't have the agent registered with the controller as its in a MTM environment.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`The machine is not ready to run tests because of the following error: Unable to connect to the controller on 'TFSSERVER.cct.local:6901.' Reason: No such host is known.`

So, it's trying to connect to `TFSSERVER.cct.local` on `port 6901`, and can't because `No such host is known.`  Sounds like a DNS issue.  Make sure that there's an entry for `TFSSERVER.cct.local` in your DNS, and it's on a network or subnet you can access. (Assuming that's actually the machine you want to connect to.)

Comment: I can ping the servers from each other, and have registered the agent with the controller manually, but I'm still getting the error. I'm not network savy, so I'm not sure what the story is with the DNS, but the two machines are on the same domain.

Comment: @ELSheepO, did you ping the domain or the IP? If you used "ping tfsserver.cct.local" and it was successful (and works from either machine to the other), it's probably not a DNS problem.

Comment: @RussAmos Ya I pinged tfsserver.cct.local, was successfull.

Comment: @ELSheepO, check your firewall settings. According to [this msdn forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vslab/thread/b531be11-1bf6-4192-bb81-920305ac36c1), you need both 6901 and 445 open for TCP into both machines.

Comment: @ELSheepO  Is NETBIOS name resolution working?  If it is, you might want to review the troubleshooting guide at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lab_management/archive/2009/10/26/troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: @RussAmos I don't think its the firewall because I can connect the controller and agent if i do it myself, but MTM Is unable to.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Those errors on the guide don't show the error I'm getting. I've gone through ones that are similar but nothing changed. I've tried reinstalling the agents and now I'm getting a error that the lab agent service is not installed, it is and it is running on the environment.